# Struggling to install a Maxx Direct to Stud Tub Surround

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, renovation, troubleshooting

I'm really struggling here and need some advice.

I'm trying to install a Maxx Tub Surround around a tub.

I've cut out the old glue in Surround and cut back the drywall to give me clearance.

Temporary bolted the thing to the studs, front and back of the tub seem level, wall studs are also level.

However the left and right side of the tub (front and back I suppose) is off by a couple inches.

Tub surround back walls go up fine, and are level.

The left and right panel do not properly seal with the trim of the tub, not do they completely sink into their locking position.. I'm assuming my issue is the tub itself, or is it just that difficult to line these dam things up?

I've included pictures of the project, hoping to get this done tonight, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

[image: Back Drywall Removed]

[image: Right Drywall Removed]

[image: Left Drywall Removed]

[image: Lower Back Wall]

[image: Upper Back Wall]

[image: Right Side Panel]

[image: Lip of the tub right panel side]

[image: Top Clip of right panel]

Comment: Kinda sounds to me like walls may not be plumb and/or square.

Comment: This is a *significant* problem: "left and right side of the tub... is off by a couple inches". These surrounds are *a little* forgiving if things are not level, plumb, and square; not "a couple inches" forgiving...

Comment: How do I go around correcting it?